# How to convert Large Integer into Date

Tags: java, date

How to convert **Large Integer** `130552992000000000` into date format?

This is today’s date and timestamp.
I tried with

```
Date d = new Date(130552992000000000L * 1000);
System.out.println("Date : " +d);
```

But its showing Date : `Wed Dec 29 00:28:58 IST 45183249` date which is incorrect and not showing year too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It does show the year. The year is 45183249. Maybe you should *divide* by 1000. Or leave the number as is. In any case you need to know what that number represents to deduce a date from it. Is it seconds since 1970-01-01? Milliseconds since then? Nanoseconds since then? 100-ns intervals since 1601-01-01? 100-ns intervals since 0001-01-01? etc.

Comment: Agree with @Joey -- that is definitely not the typical Unix milliseconds timestamp; there are far too many decimal places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Calendar#setTimeInMillis(long timemillis)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTimeInMillis%28long%29) method and the retrieve the `Date` by invoking the [Calendar#getTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime%28%29) method.

```
Long l = //some value
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(l);
Date date = c.getTime();
```

Comment: What's the problem with using the `Date` as such?! `Date` constructor does take in the milliseconds as an argument.

Comment: Because for particular dates or date arithmetics, `Calendar` is the prefered choice.

Comment: I don't see the OP mentioning Date arithmetics, and if suppose that was to be done, I would have preferred and would have recommended the OP too, to use [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) in that case!